# Manter session após fechar navegador utilizando PHP

Tags: php, session

Estou fazendo um carrinho utilizando `session`, tem como aumentar o tempo da `session`?

abaixo tem a classe que criei para o meu carrinho de compra.

```
class carrinhocompra{
public function __construct(){
    if(!isset($_SESSION['carrinho'])){
        $_SESSION['carrinho'] = array();
    }
}

public function adicionar($id, $qtd=1, $form_id=NULL){
    if(is_null($form_id)){
        $indice = sprintf("%s:%s", (int)$id, 0);

    } else {
        $indice = sprintf("%s:%s", (int)$id, (int)$form_id);
    }

    if(!isset($_SESSION['carrinho'][$indice])){
        $_SESSION['carrinho'][$indice] = (int)$qtd;
    }


}

public function aterarQtd($indice, $qtd){
    if(isset($_SESSION['carrinho'][$indice])){
        if($qtd > 0){
            $_SESSION['carrinho'][$indice] = (int)$qtd;
        }
    }
}

public function excluirProd($indice){
   unset($_SESSION['carrinho'][$indice]);
}
```

}

Comment: Se a resposta te ajudou ou resolveu seu problema, dê um voto e marque como a resposta correta, caso contrário, informe mais detalhes sobre o que tentou e os resultados. Sempre votar e escolher as respostas corretas é uma boa prática e ajuda os outros usuários.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para isso, você precisa utilizar `cookies`:

```
setcookie('carrinho', $_SESSION['carrinho'], time() + 60 * 60 * 24);
//Esse cookie expira em um dia, você pode alterar o valor de acordo com a sua necessidade
```

E na hora de mostrar o carrinho, você verifica se o `cookie` existe:

```
$carrinho = $_COOKIE['carrinho'];
```

Comment: ou editei e coloquei como esta a classe para o meu carrinho é só trocar onde está $_session para $_cookie ou tenho que fazer mais coisa?

Comment: `session` e `cookie` são duas coisas diferentes e vão trabalhar juntas, você verifica se existe algo no `cookie` e faz a leitura dele para preencher as informações do carrinho, qualquer alteração no carrinho você precisa atualizar o `cookie`. Você continua usando `sessions` como antes para as outras funcionalidades.